# CSRF verification failed although the token is in the form

Tags: python, html, django-templates, django-csrf

Hi community I am having a difficult time understanding why I get Error 403. I tried looking for answers on Stackoverflow, but the questions here are as a result of missing a `{% csrf_token %}`. Below is my html file:

```
<form action="{% url 'authentication:user_login' %}" style="display: block;" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" tabindex="1" class="form-control">

                                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" tabindex="=2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button> or <a href="{% url 'authentication:register' %}">register</a> here
                            </form>
```

Below is the view that corresponds to the url:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage'))  # main page if login is successful

            else:
                return HttpResponse("ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE")

        else:
            print('Someone tried to log in and failed')
            print('Username: {}, password, {}'.format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse('Invalid login details supplied')

    else:
        return render(request, 'authentication/login.html', {})
```

Here is the URL in the `urls.py`:

`url(r'^user_login/$', views.user_login, name='user_login'),`

I read somewhere that the csrf_token has a part to play in the render() function but I am not entirely sure what that has got to do with anything.

***EDIT***

Here is my `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

***UPDATE***

I managed to fix the problem although i am not certain if it is the proper way to solve it.
The view that is responsible for rendering that html requires it to have a return type of `render(request, authentication/login.html)` 
as compared to `HttpResponse(template.render())`

Comment: In your `request.method == "POST"`, print `request.POST` to see if `csrf_token` is passed?

Comment: @Manjunath I cannot even access my view because the csrf_token failure prevents me from. The main issue is how come the hidden input field is not being generated in the template. I noticed this when i inspected my chrome's console.

Comment: Can you show your middleware in settings.py?

Comment: You need to make sure that your browser accepts cookies from your server

Comment: I wish it was that simple. My other `register.html` form is working. It is just this `login.html` that doesnt seem to be working. What boggles me is the fact that for the csrf_token is printed nicely in chrome inspector console for one of my html but is not so for this one.

Comment: I think you made an ajax call here, so you need to pass csrf_token in the post data as something like - `csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value`

Comment: Then how come my register.html manage to succeeded without such a call? I am actually quite confused by what i see.